# Expanding Data frame with Loop. error problem

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, ambiguous, valueerror

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
    df_irrT = pd.DataFrame(data =df_irr[['id', 'Expect_NoPayments','installment', 'funded_amnt_t']])

df_irrT['0'] = df_irrT[['funded_amnt_t']]*-1000

for i in range(0, 60):
    if i <= df_irr[['Expect_NoPayments']]:
        df_irrT[i] = df_irr[['installment']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i <= df_irr[['Expect_NoPayments']]
```

is going to return a series object with True or False in each row. You cannot use it with `if` statement. `if` statement needs a True or False. You have to use any() or all() based on what you want to accomplish.